# Using a different template per Custom Taxonomies for single term archive pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, archives

I have 2 custom taxonomies, each with a number of terms:

```
tax1
  term1_1
  term1_2
tax2
  term2_1
  term2_2
  term2_3
```

I am trying to have each taxonomy usea different template file for each its single-term archive pages.  I.E.  `term1_1 and term1_2` use one template, while `term2_1 - 3` use a second one.  I can of course just load different php files conditionally from the main `archive.php` file - but I would like to know if there is a way to do this within the standard template hierarchy.

As far as I can tell, taxonomy-tax1.php doesn't work for this (unless I'm messing up royally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would intercept the template loader at `template_redirect`:

```
function wpse53892_taxonomy_template_redirect() {
    // code goes here
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse53892_taxonomy_template_redirect' );
```

Then, you would check to see if the query is a custom taxonomy:

```
if ( is_tax() ) {
    // This query is a custom taxonomy
}
```

Next, get the term object, and find out if it has a parent:

```
// Get the queried term
$term = get_queried_object();

// Determine if term has a parent;
// I *think* this will work; if not see below
if ( 0 != $term->parent ) {
    // Tell WordPress to use the parent template
    $parent = get_term( $term->parent );
    // Load parent taxonomy template
    get_query_template( 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '-' . $parent->slug . 'php' );
}

// If above doesn't work, this should:
$term_object = get_term( $term->ID );
if ( 0 != $term_object->parent; {}
```

So, putting it all together:

```
function wpse53892_taxonomy_template_redirect() {

    // Only modify custom taxonomy template redirect
    if ( is_tax() ) {
        // Get the queried term
        $term = get_queried_object();

        // Determine if term has a parent;
        // I *think* this will work; if not see above
        if ( 0 != $term->parent ) {
            // Tell WordPress to use the parent template
            $parent = get_term( $term->parent );
            // Load parent taxonomy template
            get_query_template( 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '-' . $parent->slug . 'php' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse53892_taxonomy_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Fantastic Chip. Thank you.  This problem had me really stumped back in June when I asked it.  I ended up taking a different approach entirely.  Very useful stuff in this answer that I will definitely use in the future.

Comment: I trust your WP expertise far better than my own, or I would've made the edit, but do you mean `get_queried_object()`?

Comment: Sure did. Typo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check WordPress [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png). As you can see you can use pattern `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php` to specify template for specific taxonomy and term. In your case it will be `taxonomy-tax1-term1_1.php`, etc.

Comment: Already been there, still stumped.  Your solution would require me to have a seperate php file for each term.  I want each taxonomy's terms to load from one template file

Comment: Re-reading this I realize it might be unclear...  tax1 should have 1 template file for all of its terms' archive pages.  That way, when the client adds a new term, I don't have to create a new file.

Comment: @ZachL `taxonomy-$term.php` would solve that for you. Just look further down the hierarchy chain.

Comment: not really sure what you mean by that @Chacha102

Comment: @ZachL You don't have to specify the exact term, just the taxonomy. `taxonomy-$tax.php`. Its already built into WordPress.

Comment: Hmmm.. I asked this Question several months ago, so I don't remember the specifics, nor do I have time to test, but (at least according to my original question), `taxonomy-$tax.php` apparently did *not* work... though I'm not entirely sure how/why. Has anything changed with recent versions of WP regarding this functionality?

Comment: This worked for me; thanks. I had a custom taxonomy called `issue`, so I made a template called `taxonomy-issue.php`, and WordPress picked it up automatically. The literal word `taxonomy` must be in the filename, which almost tripped me up and may confuse some.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the conditionals to target you archive page. I would use template_include like this :

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'tax_term_template', 99 );

function tax_term_template( $template ) {

    if ( "add your conditional here"  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'tax_term.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

I would [NOT use template redirect](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/) as advised by Lead Developer Mark Jaquith.